# ffmpeg-php installation error on centos

Tags: php, centos, centos5, streaming, ffmpeg

I've installed ffmpeg and and ffmpeg-php so many before and it worked, today i'm having an error

when i run `make` or `make install`, i get this error

```
make: *** [ffmpeg_frame.lo] Error 1
```

i tried these solutions [[1]](http://servertune.com/kbase/entry/373/) [[2]](http://24x7servermanagement.com/blog/?p=801) and won't fix it (at least for me), [here's how i install ffmpeg](http://servertune.com/kbase/entry/133/), i follow the first method because this post is 4 years old so many links have changed, and i don't have time to see the correct links, but this is an excellent article.

i have centos 5.4 and php 5.1.6 (yes i might update it, but if you have seen my recent post here you know that i had many problems running the newest version, well at least this version is running perfectly and apache 2.2.3 is running perfectly, i don't want to update them right now because i don't want to have troubles and then come here and ask about it)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
make: command not found
```

So, install it with:

```
# yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

and try again.

Comment: yes that's one reason lol, the other thing i wasn't replacing every PIX_FMT_RGBA32 with PIX_FMT_RGB32, i just replaced one of them lol